# Python cx_Oracle error

Tags: python, ubuntu, scrapy, cron, cx-oracle

I try to run a python scrapy crawler with crontab on Ubuntu, but i got this error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/scrapy", line 9, in <module>
    load_entry_point('Scrapy==1.0.3', 'console_scripts', 'scrapy')()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scrapy/cmdline.py", line 142, in execu$
    cmd.crawler_process = CrawlerProcess(settings)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scrapy/crawler.py", line 209, in __ini$
    super(CrawlerProcess, self).__init__(settings)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scrapy/crawler.py", line 115, in __ini$
    self.spider_loader = _get_spider_loader(settings)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scrapy/crawler.py", line 296, in _get_$
    return loader_cls.from_settings(settings.frozencopy())
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scrapy/spiderloader.py", line 30, in f$
    return cls(settings)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scrapy/spiderloader.py", line 21, in _$
    for module in walk_modules(name):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scrapy/utils/misc.py", line 71, in wal$
    submod = import_module(fullpath)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "/home/kebodev/scrapy/qgtest2/qgtest2/spiders/jsonspider.py", line 5, in <module>
    import cx_Oracle
ImportError: libclntsh.so.11.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I edit my ~/.bashrc with root user and added this lines:

```
export ORACLE_HOME=/u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/xe
export ORACLE_SID=XE
export NLS_LANG=`$ORACLE_HOME/bin/nls_lang.sh`
export ORACLE_BASE=/u01/app/oracle
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$ORACLE_HOME/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
export PATH=$ORACLE_HOME/bin:$PATH
```

My libclntsh.so.11.1 is located here: `/u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/xe/lib`

If I try to run my python scrapy crawler from terminal, it's running, and it's also works if I try to import cx_Oracle in python shell, but with crontab it's not ok..

This is how my cron job line looks like:

```
* * * * * root /etc/listarunner.sh >> /home/kebodev/scrapy/qgtest2/etcronlog1.log 2>&1
```

And this is my `listarunner.sh` file:

```
#!/bin/bash
cd /home/kebodev/scrapy/qgtest2
PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/bin
export PATH
scrapy crawl jsontst
```

Can anybody help me?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a few options you can try:

1) Set the environment variables in listarunner.sh instead of ~/.bashrc

2) Use a file in /etc/ld.so.conf.d to make the setting of LD_LIBRARY_PATH unnecessary

3) Rebuild cx_Oracle, first setting the environment variable FORCE_RPATH to any value before building.

Hopefully one of those will help you out!

Comment: So, should I put this line: export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$ORACLE_HOME/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH into the listarunner.sh file? I tried to rebuild and reinstall cx_Oracle with root user and with any other user.. and sorry but I don't understand what you mean at point number 2.:( thank you!

Comment: Yes to your first question. For the second one, if you create a file in the directory /etc/ld.so.conf.d with any name and have its contents include the directory that you want added to LD_LIBRARY_PATH the system will do it for you automatically. Without rebooting you do have to run ldconfig. For the final one, it doesn't matter which user builds it, you just have to make sure that you set FORCE_RPATH prior to building.

Comment: Thank you I'm going to try the first one.  for the second one: should I copy the whole my oracle home directory to the /etc/ld.so.conf.d directory ? Because this is what LD_LIBARY_PATH try to set. for the third one: I don't know what is FORCE_RPATH I'm really sorry but I'm really new in unix systems..

Comment: Ahh, the firs one helped me! :) thank you it's working! :)